# javascript dot after curly braces syntax error?: {num:1}.num

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

In Chrome's devtools typing this: `{num:1}.num` gives a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

...but typing this returns 1:

```
(function() {
    return {num:1}.num;
})();
```

Why do I get a syntax error in the first example but not the second?

Comment: `({num:1}.num)` is ok in chrome dev tool

Answer (score 5):

Because the braces are ambiguous in this situation, and interpreted as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), not as object literal. Something like

```
{
    num: 1
}
.num
```

Where `num:` is interpreted as [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

You can use the grouping operator to force the construct to be interpreted as expression:

```
({num: 1}).num
```

---

In the second case, the braces can only be an object literal because the return statement can only contain an expression (not a statement)

Comment: I know I can wrap parenthesis around the object to ensure correct parsing, but why did the second example not throw an error like the first?

Comment: `a = {num:1}.num;` is ok in chrome dev tool console

Comment: @web: just edited the question. In the first case, the code is ambiguous (for the parser) in the second it isn't.

Comment: @tun yes because the right hand side of an assignment expression can only be an expression , so no ambiguity here either.